# Database simulator

Tags: oracle

I've been studing theory of database, but I can't have a concrete image on terms of functionality. I want to be a DBA, I'm studing for it so I want to understand how a database works. Is there any program that simulates an actuall database so I can run logs, check performance, give maintance etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download *Oracle 12c  Enterprise Edition* Software  from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen).  You have to register but you can install it on your notebook to play with it without any license cost (but read the license agreement). If you run a 32 bit windows on you notebook you have to use Oracle 11g. In the ORACLE_HOME directory you will find a lot of scripts that demonstrate some features. You need to download and install these sample scripts as far as I know. But this is rather static.
To generate load you can use [Swingbench](http://www.dominicgiles.com/swingbench.html). Another possible tool is [Hammerora](http://hammerora.sourceforge.net/about.html) (but I have almost no experience with Hammerora).

The best way to experiment is not to install oracle directly on you machine but to install it on virtual machines. Then you can also test clusters an similar systems that need more than one machine. [Oracle Virtualbox](http://hammerora.sourceforge.net/about.html) is an appropriate solution. There are also a lot of preconfigured virtual machines from Oracle.